# Test a void method that redirect foward

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

How can I test a void method that redirects me with RequestDispatcher?

What I made until now.

```
public void testAuthAction_userNull() {
    HttpServletRequest requestMock = createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse responseMock = createMock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    expect(requestMock.getSession().getAttribute("user")).andReturn(null);
    replay(requestMock);

    AuthAction action = new AuthAction();
    RequestDispatcher rd = requestMock.getRequestDispatcher("/User/login.jsp");
}
```

the method I want to the test is.

```
public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("User");
    try {
        if(user == null) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/User/login.jsp");
            if(rd != null)
                rd.foward(request, response);
        } else {/* */}
    }
    catch(Exception e){/* */}
}
```

I'm using JUnit and EasyMock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mock of `RequestDispatcher` expecting to be forwarded, and return it from your mock:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcherMock = createMock(RequestDispatcher.class);
expect(requestMock.getRequestDispatcher("/User/login.jsp"))
    .andReturn(dispatcherMock);
// Expect to be forwarded.
dispatcherMock.forward(requestMock, responseMock);
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
replay(dispatcherMock);
replay(requestMock);

// Run your test on whatever instance has `execute`:
someInstance.execute(requestMock, responseMock);
```

Comment: on `expect(dispatcherMock.forward(requestMock, responseMock));` i get a error saying " 'void' type not allowed here "

Comment: I'm getting a exception when i try to create the mock of HttpServletResponse `HttpServletResponse responseMock = createMock.(HttpServletResponse.class)`. the exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace? Does the exception have a helpful error message?

Comment: The exception is when i try to run the test https://gist.github.com/macanhajc/03f8550d95e2f129b0a739ff6ae29658

Comment: You're missing a runtime dependency for the locale you're trying to execute the servlet environment within. That's an entirely different problem. :)

Comment: This answer assumes we want a forward. But we seem to want to test a null user so it's not really necessary at first.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a long answer that should be helpful I think.

So, the tested method is this.

```
public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("User");
    try {
        if(user == null) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/User/login.jsp");
            if(rd != null)
                rd.forward(request, response);
        } else {/* */}
    }
    catch(Exception e){/* */}
}
```

A working test method would be this:

```
@Test
public void testAuthAction_userNull() {
    HttpServletRequest requestMock = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse responseMock = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    HttpSession sessionMock = mock(HttpSession.class);

    expect(requestMock.getSession()).andReturn(sessionMock);
    expect(sessionMock.getAttribute("User")).andReturn(null);
    expect(requestMock.getRequestDispatcher("/User/login.jsp")).andReturn(null);

    replay(requestMock, sessionMock);

    execute(requestMock, responseMock);

    verify(requestMock, sessionMock);
}
```

I am using `mock()` instead of `createMock()`. It's the same but nicer and shorter.

It returns a null dispatcher because nothing more is needed. I've added a `verify()` to make sure everything was called as expected.

Then, if you want to make sure the forward is called as well, you also need a mock for the `RequestDispatcher`.

```
@Test
public void testAuthAction_userNull() throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest requestMock = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse responseMock = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    HttpSession sessionMock = mock(HttpSession.class);
    RequestDispatcher rdMock = mock(RequestDispatcher.class);

    expect(requestMock.getSession()).andReturn(sessionMock);
    expect(sessionMock.getAttribute("User")).andReturn(null);
    expect(requestMock.getRequestDispatcher("/User/login.jsp")).andReturn(rdMock);

    rdMock.forward(requestMock, responseMock);

    replay(requestMock, sessionMock, rdMock);

    execute(requestMock, responseMock);

    verify(requestMock, sessionMock, rdMock);
}
```

The `verify()` will make sure `forward()` is called. You do not need an `expectLastCall()`. It is implicit.

Then to simplify, I would actually do this:

```
public class MyTest extends EasyMockSupport {
    @Test
    public void testAuthAction_userNull() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest requestMock = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse responseMock = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        HttpSession sessionMock = mock(HttpSession.class);
        RequestDispatcher rdMock = mock(RequestDispatcher.class);

        expect(requestMock.getSession()).andReturn(sessionMock);
        expect(sessionMock.getAttribute("User")).andReturn(null);
        expect(requestMock.getRequestDispatcher("/User/login.jsp")).andReturn(rdMock);

        rdMock.forward(requestMock, responseMock);

        replayAll();

        execute(requestMock, responseMock);

        verifyAll();
    }
}
```

The `EasyMockSupport` class makes the code simpler.

And to be honest, in this case, when using Spring, I would use `spring-test`.

```
@Test
public void testAuthAction_userNull() throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

    execute(request, response);

    assertThat(response.getForwardedUrl()).isEqualTo("/User/login.jsp");
}
```

It does the exact same thing but as you can see it is much shorter because the session and request dispatcher are created under the hood to behave like you would expect.