# How to set attributes with easymock

Tags: session, mocking, easymock

I need to mock a request with a session, the session has an attribute (project)

```
    HttpServletRequest req = createNiceMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpSession session = createNiceMock(HttpSession.class);
    session.setAttribute("currentProject", project); // project is not null here
    expect(req.getSession()).andReturn(session);            
    replay(req);
```

But the test produces a `NullPointerException` in the following code

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Project p = (Project) session.getAttribute("currentProject");
```

Project p is null after that line. Why??

Answer (score 1):

You are not recording anything for `getAttribute`. `session` is a mock. So you can't set anything to it. You need to record calls.

A working version of this code would be

```
HttpServletRequest req = createNiceMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpSession session = createNiceMock(HttpSession.class);
expect(session.getAttribute("currentProject").andReturn(project);
expect(req.getSession()).andReturn(session);
replay(req, session);
```

Note that I recommend using spring-test instead of EasyMock if you are in a Spring context. It makes testing much simpler. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106350/test-a-void-method-that-redirect-foward/50137752#50137752) to another question.